# JavaScript using multiple functions to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit

Tags: javascript, function

I want to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa using multiple functions.

one way I have done it, it's like this:

```js
function cToF(Cel) {
  var cTemp = Cel;
  var cToFah = cTemp * 9 / 5 + 32;
  var msg = cTemp + "\xB0C is " + cToFah + " \xB0F.";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = msg;
}

function fToC(Fah) {
  var fTemp = Fah;
  var fToCels = (fTemp - 32) * 5 / 9;
  var msg = fTemp + "\xB0F is " + fToCels + "\xB0C.";
  document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = msg;
}

cToF(60);
fToC(45);
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="result2"></p>
```

But I want to create multiple functions inside one function to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit.
for example in the function `cToF()` whatever value the function gets, it should then call four other different functions like:

"

```
Add()this function should add 32, 
Sub()this function should subtract 32, 
Mul()this function should multiple by 32, 
Div()this function should divide by 9
```

"

and then convert the Celsius value to Fahrenheit and vice versa.

Maybe it's not practical but I want to learn this and more about JavaScript!

Comment: So what is the problem? Create those functions and call them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want like below. I just created that function and call then from `cToF()` and `fToC()`

```js
function add(a,b){
    return a+b;
}
function sub(a,b){
    return a-b;
}
function mul(a,b){
    return a*b;
}
function div(a,b){
    return a/b;
}
function cToF(Cel) 
{
  var cTemp = Cel;
  var cToFah = add(div(mul(cTemp, 9), 5), 32);
  var msg = cTemp + "\xB0C is " + cToFah + " \xB0F.";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = msg;
}

function fToC(Fah) 
{
  var fTemp = Fah;
  var fToCels = div(mul(sub(fTemp, 32), 5), 9);
  var msg = fTemp + "\xB0F is " + fToCels + "\xB0C.";
  document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = msg;
} 
cToF(60);
fToC(45);
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="result2"></p>
```